# How Keras use Glorot Uniform and Relu?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

i want to ask how Keras process an input using Glorot uniform initializer and relu?
I am confused how Keras process the input

For example i have a code like this

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1), input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
model.add(Convolution2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2)))

model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(4096, (1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Convolution2D(2622, (1, 1)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

I know the RELU activation function used in ConvNet as the computational step. RELU will set value of any negative elements to 0 otherwise set to 1 if positive. But how they process an input like above.

`Input -> Glorot -> RELU` or `Input -> RELU -> Glorot`?
Anybody can explain to me?

Comment: shouldn't he initialization be used with relu? not glorot initialization?

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax already explained below mate. Glorot do initialization first, then multiplied input and lastly RELU

Comment: i’m saying “dont use glorot w relu. use he”

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax he? what's he? and why?

Comment: It is a type of initialization just like glorot. I’ve been reading that certain activations do better w certain inits.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax i don't use that because my research use VGG-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is Glorot uniform and how does it work?

According to Keras documentation,

> Glorot uniform initializer, also called Xavier uniform initializer.
>   It draws samples from a uniform distribution within [-limit, limit] where limit is sqrt(6 / (fan_in + fan_out)) where fan_in is the number of input units in the weight tensor and fan_out is the number of output units in the weight tensor.

It is just an initializer which initializes the weights of each layer in Keras. It opts for a different strategy. It calculates the limit [ -limit , limit ] where limit = sqrt( 6 /( input units + output units ) ) . Then the weights are chosen randomly from the [ -limit , limit ].

> How does all this stuff work in a sequence in Keras?

The following steps are followed.

1. Initialize the weights using glorot uniform.
2. The input vector is multiplied with the weight matrix.
3. Add a bias to the above dot product.
4. Perform ReLU activation to the above sum.

Hence,

```
Glorot_Uniform  -> Input -> ReLU
```

Comment: where i can see the step documentation from 1 to 4?

Comment: Well, it is not documented in Keras. But, it is a standard procedure which all NN follow.

Comment: how about the weight matrix on step 2? Where i can see the matrix?